# Am Samstag, dem/den

Tags: preposition, grammatical-case, article, time

In einem Hueber-Trainer steht Folgendes:

> Am Samstag, **den** 23. Mai 2009, findet um 19.00 Uhr bei uns zu Hause ein
>   kleines Geburtstagsfest statt, zu dem ich Sie sehr herzlich einlade.

Ich dachte, auf *an* folgt der Dativ, also *dem.* Ist *den* hier ein Tippfehler, oder ist es doch korrekt?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mein Gefühl sowie der Duden [1] sagen, dass es in diesem Fall in der Tat

> Am Samstag, dem 23. Mai 2009

heißen muss, weil nach "am" der Dativ kommt.

Interessant ist dabei jedoch, dass bei sehr ähnlichem Satz, nur ohne "am", der Akkusativ steht (Beispiel aus dem Duden):

> Die Familie kommt Montag, den 5. September[,] um 12 Uhr[,] an.

Und traditionell schreibt man ja auch, zum Beispiel in Briefen oder altmodischen Tagebüchern in der Datumsangabe am Anfang der Seite oder des Abschnitts:

> Mittwoch, den 6. September 2017 - Heute war ein schrecklicher Tag. Am frühen Morgen erreichte mich...

Der Duden formuliert dazu als Regel: "Bei einer Datumsangabe ohne „am" oder „vom" steht der Monatstag im Akkusativ."

Anders jedoch, wenn der Tag nicht als Datumsangabe dient, sondern selbst Subjekt des Satzes (also Nominativ) ist:

> Mittwoch, der 6. September 2017, war ein schrecklicher Tag.

---

[1] http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/datumsangaben-die-mit-am-eingeleitet-werden

Comment: Christian: ich bin mit Dir einverstanden - Akk. in so einem Fall wie „Heute haben wir Montag, den ...“. Aber würdet Ihr als Muttersprachler tatsächlich sagen  „Die Familie kommt Montag“? Ohne Präposition? Ich dachte, in solchen Fällen wenn wir meinen, an einem Tag geschieht etw. bzw. findet etw. statt ist die Präposition obligatorisch oder etwa nicht?

Comment: In mündlicher Sprache kann man auf jeden Fall "Die Familie kommt Montag" sagen. Das ist vermutlich sogar die häufigere Variante (vielleicht unterschiedlich je nach Region). Im schriftlichen Verkehr würde man dann aber doch "Die Familie kommt am Montag" formulieren.

Comment: Christian: vielen Dank für die Erklärung! habe was dazu gelernt! =) wäre dann so ein Beispielsatz korrekt: „Ich komme Montag/Montagabend in München an“? (mit dem Vermerk Umgangssprache)

Comment: The URL leads to a completely different article. Also, https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/datum (from https://german.stackexchange.com/a/41168/39628) contradicts the first part of your answer.

Answer (score 6):

Duden Webseite, [D32](http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/datum):

> Bei Datumsangaben mit *am* kann der Kalendertag im Dativ oder im Akkusativ stehen.
>
> - Die Familie kommt am Montag, dem/den 5. September[,] an.

Vgl. *Der Große Duden Grammatik* 5785:

> *β*) Zu den nachgetragenen Appositionen gehören auch die Datumsangaben. Der Monatstag steht deshalb im gleichen Kasus wie der als Bezugswort stehende Wochentag:
>
> ... am Montag, dem 14. März 1908, ...
>
> ... Montag, den 14. März 1908, ...
>
> Beachte:
>
> Bei der Datumsangabe [am] Montag, den 25. Januar ging ich ... ist der Monatstag keine Apposition zum Bezugswort Montag, sondern eine selbständige Zeitangabe im Akkusativ neben der ebenso selbständigen Zeitangabe [am] Montag. Es handelt sich hier um eine Aufzählung.

Am Samstag, dem 23. Mai 2009 = Apposition

Am Samstag, den 23. Mai 2009 = zwei selbständige Zeitangaben

Answer (score 0):

Bastian Sick (»Der Dativ ist dem Genitiv sein Tod«) hat einen interessanten Artikel hierzu veröffentlicht:

http://bastiansick.de/kolumnen/fragen-an-den-zwiebelfisch/am-montag-dem-oder-den/

Damit sind beide Schreibungen möglich und es kommt, wie üblich, immer darauf an…

Comment: Aber alle Beispiele bei Herrn Sick machen es doch genau so, wie auch der Herr Duden es nahelegt... ?

Comment: Das wäre eine Frage für belleslettres.eu