# Why is "den" used in "am Montag, den 10. August''?

Tags: grammatical-case, time, definite-article

> **This question also has an answer here (in German):**
>   *[Am Samstag, dem/den](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/38932/am-samstag-dem-den)*

It's more logical to me to be "am Montag, dem 10. August" since without specifying Monday, I would say "am 10. August"  Instead, it's like the article is taking on adjectival endings.

Comment: Nobody so far has answered the "why" question. I am not able to give an exhaustive and robust answer, too, but I think a good answer will mention traditions of writing dates in chanceries from, say, the mit 18th century (i.e. when modern bureaucracy was developed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the rules (for example [Duden](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/datum) or [canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Adjektiv/Zahlen/Ordinal.html#Anchor-Datumsangaben-21683)) both variants are correct. After a date specification with "am" one can use dative or accusative for the calender day, so one can write

> am Montag, den 10. August
> am Montag, dem 10. August

So, the "why" has to be answered that it is layed down by definition that both variants are possible.

Comment: Looks like a partial answer to me as it does not address the "why?".

Comment: @user1583209 Good point. I tried to add the "why".

Answer (score 4):

The accusative case is used when referring to a day or month without the preposition "an" preceding it. For example:

> Jeden Freitag freue ich mich auf die Ankunft von meinem Freund.

Or

> Ich habe für meine Chefin eine Verabredung nächsten Montag um 8:00 Uhr gebucht.

However with "an", the dative case is always used:

> Am Montag müssen wir einkaufen gehen.

Answer (score -2):

I always understood that the accusative is used in dates  I.e den vierten April , because you are really saying 'Heute haben wir  den vierten April' not just nominative ! Heute ist der vierte April , is not said.

Comment: *Heute ist der vierte April.* is perfectly fine.