# Wortart/Wortform von "*nächsten Freitag* habe ich einen Termin*

Tags: grammatical-case, noun, adverb

Nehmen wir das Beispiel

> Nächsten Freitag kann ich nicht. Da habe ich einen Arzttermin.

Wie würde man *Freitag* qualifizieren?

Es könnte kurz für "*am* (nächsten) Freitag" sein. Das sieht man auch daran, dass *nächsten* im Akkusativ steht. Zudem schreibt man es groß. Dann müsste *Freitag* ein Nomen sein, nicht?
Andererseits gibt es Gegenbeispiele dazu:

> Nächste Woche kann ich nicht.

Hier steht *nächste Woche* nicht im Dativ, was kurz für *in der nächsten Woche* wäre.

Außerdem spricht gegen die Qualifikation als Nomen, dass *Freitag* genauso verwendet wird wie *da* in *Da habe ich einen Arzttermin*. Demnach wäre es wohl ein Adverb.

Comment: Ich verstehe die Frage nicht... hilft [dieser Link](https://mein-deutschbuch.de/temporale-praepositionen.html)?

Comment: Woche ist feminin: die Woche. Dativ: die Woche... "Nächste Woche" ist also Dativ in Deinem Beispiel...

Comment: Es handelt sich um Akkusativ, Dativ wäre *der Woche*

Comment: Was ist urortart? Habe leider nichts dazu gefunden, das ich mit Sprache verbinde. Danke.

Comment: Was ist "*urortart*" (im Titel)? Sollte das "*Wortart*" heißen?

Comment: Das erste Wort eines Satzes schreibt man wegen seiner Position groß. Freitag ist immer ein Nomen, freitags hingegen nicht. Das nächste Missverständnis ist: der Freitag, die Woche - das sind schon mal verschiedene Artikel für die Substantive im Nominativ.

Comment: "*am Freitag*" ist Dativ, nicht Akkusativ

Comment: Related [question](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/41167/1696) handling cases in date context.

Answer (score 4):

Man könnte von einem *temporalen Akkusativ* sprechen.

Zeitangaben ohne Präposition stehen üblicherweise im Akkusativ:

> Nächste Woche kann ich nicht.
>
> Diesen Freitag gehe ich ins Kino.

Mit Präposition wird dagegen der Dativ verwendet:

> In der nächsten Woche kann ich nicht.
>
> An diesem Freitag gehe ich ins Kino.

Answer (score 1):

"[Freitag](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Freitag)" und "[Woche](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Woche)" gehören zur Wortart der Nomen. Dafür ist es unerheblich, in welchem Fall sie stehen oder zu welchem Satzteil sie gehören.