# How to write date at the end of a CV?

Tags: grammatical-case, time

At the end of a CV, do we write:

> Musterort, der 25.08.2021

Or:

> Musterort, den 25.08.2021

Or are both acceptable?

Comment: Related [question](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/41167/1696).

Comment: If you want to be avantgarde (i.e., following the [international standard since 1988](https://xkcd.com/1179/) :-)), you can write `Musterort, [der/den] 2021-08-25`. I made writing dates like this everywhere a principle of mine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Neither [DIN 5008](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIN_5008) nor [Duden](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/datum) state clear rules for that. So let's not talk about right or wrong but about style.

> Musterort, den 25.08.2021

is kind of old-fashioned but ok.

> Musterort, der 25.08.2021

is weird. The part *der [Datum]* is used as post clarification if you write something like

> Freitag, der 21.03.1823

You want to specify what Friday you are talking about and therefore use a comma-separated *der [Datum]*.

In your example you state the place instead of the weekday. So it's not a clarification but an additional information separated by comma.

Just drop the article and write simply

> München, 25.08.2021

Comment: Can you please clarify why the accusative case can be used in "den 25.08.2021"? Is it the same as "jeden Tag"?

Comment: @KeNSmilePachI It's a convention and a pretty old one. "Ortsangabe, den Datumsangabe" is a fixed construction and not actually part of a sentence. It's not really known why the accusative is used, maybe it's short for "Wir schreiben den 25.08.2021.", which is a sentence you could find in historical (like in the middle ages) letters.

Comment: @KeNSmilePachI: See the linked question in my comment above.

Comment: @guidot That question is about a related but different issue.

Answer (score 1):

> Musterort, 25.08.2021

or

> Musterort, **am** 25.08.2021

"der" and "den" doesn't really fit here at the end of a letter.

You're signing it as "in this place, on this date" so "Musterort, am XX.XX.XXXX" would fit the best. You can however just just use "Musterort, 25.08.2021"

Comment: '"den" doesn't really fit here at the end of a letter.' is simply wrong.

Comment: But it's not a letter, it's a CV to apply for a job

Comment: @Roland any reason why it would fit?  Because I really don't see it fitting unless the format is entirely different in the first place

Comment: @KeNSmilePachI a CV would traditionally be sent as a letter, even as an email it would still have to stick to a "letter" format

Comment: Because it is a common convention to end a German letter with <place>, den <date> <signature>.